# Prove the Algorithm Analysis Theorem

Tags: math, analysis, discrete-mathematics

I do not have any idea how can I prove that algorithm analysis or discrete math question:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the logarithms, you rewrite the inequality as `k Lg(n) < n`, or `n / Lg(n) > k`.

The function `f(n) = n / Lg(n)` is increasing and unbounded for `n > 3`.

(`f'(n) = (Lg(n) - Lg(e)) / Lg²(n) > 0`.)